# SQL Server : how can I filter a many to many relationship with delimiter

Tags: sql-server

I have a `Disease` and a `Symptoms` table with a bridge table of `Disease_Symptoms`

For example I have these entries

```
Disease1  
    (symptoms1, symptoms2, symptoms6, symptoms7)

Disease2  
    (symptoms1, symptoms3, symptoms8)

Disease3  
    (symptoms1, symptoms4)

Disease4
    (symptoms2, symptoms8)
```

Then I filter a search using `symptoms1`:

OUTPUT:

```
disease1, disease2, disease3
```

Then I want to add a filter search of `symptoms8`

The OUTPUT should be: `disease2` only (`disease4` is ignored because it doesn't have `symptoms1`)

How do I do that in query? I created a stored procedure but it can only search a single symptom and no more.

I asked a colleague regarding about this problem, he told me I need to use comma delimiter, but I don't know how. I couldn't understand some examples in other sites.

Can you at least show me a little of that method in a basic understandable manner?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_RetrieveDiseaseSymptoms
    @Id int = 0
    ,@DiseaseId int = 0
    ,@SymptomId int = 0
    ,@Toggle bit = 0
    ,@UserId int = 0
    ,@SearchText AS NVARCHAR(100) = ''
    ,@SearchCriteria AS NVARCHAR(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
      ISNULL(DS.Id,0) as Id
      ,ISNULL(DS.DiseaseId, 0) as DiseaseId
      ,ISNULL(D.DiseaseName, '') as DiseaseName
      ,ISNULL(D.Description, '') as Description
      ,ISNULL(DS.SymptomId, 0) as SymptomId
      ,ISNULL(S.Name, '') as SymptomName
      ,ISNULL(DS.StatusId, 0) as StatusId
      ,ISNULL(DS.CreatedBy, 1) as CreatedById
      ,CB.FirstName + ', ' + CB.LastName as CreatedByName
      ,ISNULL(DS.CreatedOn, '1/1/1753') as CreatedOn
      ,ISNULL(DS.ModifiedBy, 1) as ModifiedById
      ,CM.LastName + ', ' + CM.FirstName as CreatedByName
      ,ISNULL(DS.ModifiedOn , '1/1/1753')as ModifiedOn     
    FROM 
       Disease_Symptoms DS  

    LEFT JOIN 
       Users CB ON CB.Id = DS.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN 
       Users CM ON CM.Id = DS.ModifiedBy
    LEFT JOIN 
       Diseases D ON D.Id = DS.DiseaseId
    LEFT JOIN 
       Symptoms S ON S.Id = DS.SymptomId

    WHERE 
       (DS.Id = @Id OR @Id = 0) 
       AND (D.Id = @DiseaseId OR @DiseaseId = 0)
       AND (S.Id = @SymptomId OR @SymptomId = 0)      
       AND DS.StatusId <> 0 

END
GO
```

Sample data

```
==============

Diseases table

D_Id  D_name

1     AIDS

2     Bird Flu

3     Mad Cow

4     Osteoporosis

==============

Symptoms table

S_Id   S_name

1      Drooling

2      Blurred retina

3      Cough

4      Fever

5      Yellowish gums

6      Dark blue tongue

7      Falling furs

8      Poor appetite

==============

Disease_Symptoms table

DS_Id   D_Id   S_Id

1        1      1 (AIDS - Drooling)

2        1      2 (AIDS - Blurred retina)

3        1      6 (AIDS - Dark blue tongue)

4        1      7 (AIDS - Falling furs)

5        2      1 (Bird flu - Drooling)

6        2      3 (Bird flu - Cough)

7        2      8 (Bird flu - Poor appetite)

8        3      1 (Mad cow - Drooling)

9        3      4 (Mad cow - Fever)

10       4      2 (Osteoporosis - Blurred retina)

11       4      8 (Osteoporosis - Poor appetite)
```

Then I'm gonna search any disease that has a symptom of: Drooling (symptom_id = 1)

output:

```
AIDS
Bird flu
Mad cow
```

Then, I wanna add another symptom, but the query should just search between the three previous outputs(AIDS, Bird flu, Mad cow) and ignore the last disease(Osteoporosis) since it doesn't have symptom_id = 1 (Drooling).

Search symptom: Poor appetite (symptom_id = 8)

output:

```
Bird flu
```

Comment: Provide a sample data set and the desired result.

Comment: Done editing. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think you're looking for "relational division". Also, BTW, you should avoid the `SP_` prefix on stored procedure names - it's reserved for Microsoft's system procedures and in the event of a conflict, the Microsoft one will win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approacahes depending on how you want to display the answer:

You can take the input string and convert it to a table (lookup fn_split to see how), then you can count the number of matches and only take the records where teh count matches the total records in the temp table.

```
create table #temp (id int)

Insert into #temp
values (1), (2), (3)

create table #temp2 (testid int,id int, test varchar (30))

insert into #temp2
values (1,1, 'test') ,(1,5, 'test2'), (2,1,'Test3') ,(2,2,'test4'), (2,3, 'test5')

select  tp2.testid, tp2.id, tp2.test from #temp2 tp2
join (select testid from #temp2 t2
join #temp t on t.id = t2.id
group by testid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from #temp)) mycount
on tp2.testid = mycount.testid
```

Or you can use you input string variable and FOR XML PATH to display the concatenated value

```
declare @Concatstg varchar(100) = '1,2,3'
select *
from
(
        select distinct t2.testid, STUFF((SELECT  ',' + cast(t1.id as varchar (20) )
        FROM #temp2  t1 where t2.testid = t1.testid 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  as Concatstr
        from #temp2 t2
     ) Derivedtable     
where        Concatstr = @Concatstg
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here's one way:

```
SELECT D_name
FROM Diseases d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Disease_Symptoms ds1 WHERE ds1.D_id=d.D_id AND ds1.S_id=1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Disease_Symptoms ds8 WHERE ds8.D_id=d.D_id AND ds8.S_id=8)
```